# webpack source maps devtool config in Core2 Vue project debugging in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core-2.2, vue-cli

I am struggling to configure webpack 4 to be able to debug my Vue js code inside my .net Core 2.2 web application.

I have played around with source map devtool and also devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate in webpack config but so far nothing work.

The example project for my question is here:

https://github.com/hoiratnhieu/VueRedballDebug

I would like to see the end result of the redball breakpoint is hit at a javascript/vue line when I run my web application in debug mode (IIS Express in Visual Studio 2019)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Viet, could you provide more context about your issue?  What kinds of errors/messages are you seeing?

Comment: Hi, there is no error message of any kind, my test sample (github above) ran successfully with debug mode in iisexpress. However, breakpoints in visual studio would not be hit as expected.
So again, my question was solely about how to setup to achieve breakpoint in debug mode in this sample environment.
Thank you.